# Unable to Start Stepper Motor Using TMC2209 and ESP32

Tags: c, esp32, esp-idf

I'm having trouble getting my stepper motor to start using a TMC2209 driver and an ESP32 microcontroller.
Could someone please help me troubleshoot this issue and guide me through the steps to successfully start the stepper motor?

This is my code:

```
#define STEP 38
#define EN 37
#define DIR 36
#define INDEX 35
#define DIAG 21
#define MS2 13
#define MS1 14
#define PDN_RX 11
#define PDN_TX 10
#define TX 43
#define RX 44

uint8_t GCONF[] = {0xA, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00};
uint8_t FACTORY_CONF[] = {0xA, 0x00, 0x87, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x00};
uint8_t IHOLD_IRUN[] = {0xA,0x00,0x90,0x00,0x49,0x49,0x00};
uint8_t TPOWERDOWN[] = {0xA, 0x00, 0x91, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00};
uint8_t TPWMTHRS[] = {0xA, 0x00, 0x93, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
uint8_t VACTUAL[] = {0xA, 0x00, 0xA2, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00};
uint8_t SGTHRS[] = {0xA, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x50, 0x00};
uint8_t COOLCONF[] = {0xA, 0x00, 0xC2, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB0, 0x66, 0x00};

const uart_port_t uart_num = UART_NUM_0;

uint8_t CalcCRC (uint8_t * datagram, uint8_t datagramLength) {
  int i, j; /* Loop Counters */
  uint8_t *crc = datagram + (datagramLength - 1);  // CRC located in last byte of message
  uint8_t currentByte;                            // Byte to be sent
  *crc = 0;                                      // Initialize CRC to 0
  for (i = 0; i < (datagramLength - 1); i++) {  // Execute for all bytes of a message
      currentByte = datagram[i];               // Retrieve a byte to be sent from Array
      for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {               // Execute for all bits of a byte
          if ((*crc >> 7) ^ (currentByte & 0x01)) { // update CRC based result of XOR operation
              *crc = (*crc << 1) ^ 0x07; // Shift CRC to the left and XOR with 0x07
          } /*of if*/
          else {
              *crc = (*crc << 1); // Shift CRC to the left
          } /*of else*/
          currentByte = currentByte >> 1; /* Shift byte to the right once */
      } /*of for j counter*/
  } /*of for datagram length*/
  return datagram[datagramLength - 1]; // Return the CRC
} /*of CalcCRC*/

void CalcRegistersCrc() 
{
    uint8_t CRC = CalcCRC((const char *)GCONF, sizeof(GCONF));
    printf("%02X\n", CRC);
    CRC = CalcCRC((const char *)FACTORY_CONF, sizeof(FACTORY_CONF));
    printf("%02X\n", CRC);
    CRC = CalcCRC((const char *)IHOLD_IRUN, sizeof(IHOLD_IRUN));
    printf("%02X\n", CRC);
    CRC = CalcCRC((const char *)TPOWERDOWN, sizeof(TPOWERDOWN));
    printf("%02X\n", CRC);
    CRC = CalcCRC((const char *)TPWMTHRS, sizeof(TPWMTHRS));
    printf("%02X\n", CRC);
    CRC = CalcCRC((const char *)VACTUAL, sizeof(VACTUAL));
    printf("%02X\n", CRC);
    CRC = CalcCRC((const char *)SGTHRS, sizeof(SGTHRS));
    printf("%02X\n", CRC);
    CRC = CalcCRC((const char *)COOLCONF, sizeof(COOLCONF));
    printf("%02X\n", CRC);
}

void WriteRegisters()
{
    uart_write_bytes(uart_num, GCONF, sizeof(GCONF));
    uart_write_bytes(uart_num, FACTORY_CONF, sizeof(FACTORY_CONF));
    uart_write_bytes(uart_num, IHOLD_IRUN, sizeof(IHOLD_IRUN));
    uart_write_bytes(uart_num, TPOWERDOWN, sizeof(TPOWERDOWN));
    uart_write_bytes(uart_num, TPWMTHRS, sizeof(TPWMTHRS));
    uart_write_bytes(uart_num, VACTUAL, sizeof(VACTUAL));
    uart_write_bytes(uart_num, SGTHRS, sizeof(SGTHRS));
    uart_write_bytes(uart_num, COOLCONF, sizeof(COOLCONF));
    
  
    ESP_LOGI("STEPPER MOTOR", "All registers are written");
}

void SetPins()
{
    gpio_set_direction(EN, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(MS1, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(MS2, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);

    gpio_set_level(EN, 0);
    gpio_set_level(MS1, 0);
    gpio_set_level(MS2, 1);
}

void InitUart()
{
    uart_config_t uart_config = {
        .baud_rate = 115200,
        .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
        .parity = UART_PARITY_DISABLE,
        .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
        .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_DISABLE,
        .source_clk = UART_SCLK_APB
    };

    uart_param_config(uart_num, &uart_config);
    uart_set_pin(uart_num, TX, RX, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE);
    uart_driver_install(uart_num, 2048, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
}


void ReadData()
{
    ;
}

void StepperMotorTask(void *pvParameters)
{   
    CalcRegistersCrc();
    SetPins();
    InitUart();
    while (1)
    {
        WriteRegisters();
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}
```

I've followed the wiring diagram and set up the necessary pins, but the motor doesn't seem to respond. I've double-checked my connections but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 3):

One bug is the sloppy formatting, which would have been immediately spotted if proper formatting had been used instead:

```c
uint8_t GCONF[] =        {0xA, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00};
uint8_t FACTORY_CONF[] = {0xA, 0x00, 0x87, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1F, 0x00};
uint8_t IHOLD_IRUN[] =   {0xA, 0x00, 0x90, 0x00, 0x49, 0x49, 0x00};       // hmm...
uint8_t TPOWERDOWN[] =   {0xA, 0x00, 0x91, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00};
uint8_t TPWMTHRS[] =     {0xA, 0x00, 0x93, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
uint8_t VACTUAL[] =      {0xA, 0x00, 0xA2, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00};
uint8_t SGTHRS[] =       {0xA, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x50, 0x00};
uint8_t COOLCONF[] =     {0xA, 0x00, 0xC2, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB0, 0x66, 0x00};
```